# JHelpDev missing titles in search

Tags: java

I am using JHelpDev to create a help window for an application. Everything is working fine except that when I use the search feature the results are displayed as all saying "No Title". clicking on one of the results bring up a page with the correct number of results highlighted it just labels everything as "No Title". Does anyone know how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDevHelp uses text wrapped in

```
<h1></h1>
```

tags as the title for the index